# Is it possible to extending month view not an empty FC.View.extend? (Full Calendar)

Tags: fullcalendar

I think I'm missing something or I just not understand how it works.

Can I do something like this.

`var CustomView = fcViews.basic.extend({});`
or
`var CustomView = BasicView.extend({});`

OR according to documentations http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/
you can only do this `var CustomView = View.extend({});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from fullCalendar.View class, doesn't matter how you name it.

```
var FC = $.fullCalendar; // a reference to FullCalendar's root namespace
var View = FC.View;      // the class that all views must inherit from
```

You need to extend that object that in the example is named as `View`

Comment: I would like to inherit from BasicView class not from an empty View class. The BasicView extend the View class already.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i created a custom view:

```
var TwoWeeks = fcViews.twoweeks = BasicView.extend({
    // Computes the new date when the user hits the prev button, given the current date
    initialize: function() {
        this.dayGrid = new DayGrid(this);
        this.coordMap = this.dayGrid.coordMap; // the view's date-to-cell mapping is identical to the subcomponent's

        // subclasses can implement
        var navJump = this.opt('twoWeekNavJump');
        if (navJump) {
            this.intervalDuration = moment.duration({'weeks': navJump});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This could be the best options, but the only problem I have with this is if I do this `new DayGrid(this);` it will give me this `Uncaught ReferenceError: DayGrid is not defined` then I have to add DayGrid and I have two of the same code one in fullCalendar.js and for the custom view.

Comment: this is code that i have in the fullcalendar source; then do a custom build. I'm not sure how else you import a custom view.